# Padding on images in UITableView cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I've successfully setup a mini app which has a table of titles, descriptions and images. Problem is, the images are butted up to the left and it leaves barely any room between cells.

Is there anyway to maybe put some padding in there to give it a bit of space?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include more code/what you have tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just change the frame of the cell's `imageView`

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

If you want to move it away from the left, set the x to anything higher than 0.

Comment: No, it did not work. You need to subclass UITableViewCell and override layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and solved using:

```
cell.indentationWidth = xxx;
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Hope this helps others.